# How to insert a table column using td selector containing a link

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have the following table row:

```html
<tr>
  <td><a href="http://...?page=1&oID=5&action=edit"><img src="images/icons/preview.gif" border="0" alt="Preview" title="Preview" /></a>&nbsp;Customer Name</td>
  <td class="dataTableContent" align="right">32.19€</td>
  <td class="dataTableContent" align="center">11/29/2019 18:53:49</td>
  <td class="dataTableContent" align="right">Delivered</td>
  <td class="dataTableContent" align="right"><img src="images/icon_arrow_right.gif" border="0" alt="" />&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Now I would like to select the first td with the link using the oID=5 parameter and insert a new column after the 3rd column "Delivered",
My jquery is:

```js
$(function() {
  $('td:has(a[href$="oID=5&action=edit"]) td:eq(3)').after('<td class="dataTableContent" align="center">2019-12-05 14:10:20</td>');
});
```

Tried many variants, but do not get it to work.

Comment: I got one step closer: <script>
$(function() {
$('td:has([href$="oID=5&action=edit"]):eq(2)').after('<td class="dataTableContent" align="center">2019-12-05 14:10:20</td>');
});
</script>inserts the column after the first column containing the link. But still no success to move it after third column,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the table and after that, you can find the `oID=5`

```js
$(function() {

index = $(this).find( '[href$="oID=5&action=edit"]').index();
       $('td:eq(' + index +3 + ')' ).after('<td class="dataTableContent" align="center">2019-12-05 14:10:20</td>')

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td><a href="http://...?page=1&oID=5&action=edit"><img src="images/icons/preview.gif" border="0" alt="Preview" title="Preview" /></a>&nbsp;Customer Name</td>
  <td class="dataTableContent" align="right">32.19€</td>
  <td class="dataTableContent" align="center">11/29/2019 18:53:49</td>
  <td class="dataTableContent" align="right">Delivered</td>
  <td class="dataTableContent" align="right"><img src="images/icon_arrow_right.gif" border="0" alt="" />&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. On my page it doesn't work correct because I have nested tables. I get the column inserted at the end of the header.
Here I post the complete table with the script. Although running it here it seems not to work at all.

```js
<script>
$(function() {
  $('.dataTableHeadingContent:eq(1)').before('<td class="dataTableHeadingContent" align="center">Request sent</td>');
  index = $(this).find( '[href$="oID=5&action=edit"]').index();
       $('td:eq(' + index +3 + ')' ).after('<td class="dataTableContent" align="center">2019-12-05 14:10:20</td>')
});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%"><table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
          <tr class="dataTableHeadingRow">
            <td class="dataTableHeadingContent">Customers</td>
            <td class="dataTableHeadingContent" align="right">Order Total</td>
            <td class="dataTableHeadingContent" align="center">Date Purchased</td>
            <td class="dataTableHeadingContent" align="right">Status</td>
            <td class="dataTableHeadingContent" align="right">Action&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="defaultSelected" class="dataTableRowSelected">
            <td class="dataTableContent"><a href="http://localhost/...?page=1&oID=5&action=edit"><img src="images/icons/preview.gif" border="0" alt="Preview" title="Preview" /></a>&nbsp;Rainer Schmied</td>
            <td class="dataTableContent" align="right">25.53€</td>
            <td class="dataTableContent" align="center">11/28/2019 11:12:13</td>
            <td class="dataTableContent" align="right">Pending</td>
            <td class="dataTableContent" align="right"><img src="images/icon_arrow_right.gif" border="0" alt="" />&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

The best aproach I found until now is this:

```
$('td:has([href$="oID={$orders_id}&action=edit"]):eq(2)').after('<td class="dataTableContent" align="center">{$request_date}</td>');
```

It inserts the column as second column, just after the selected column with the link.

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it now. The problem was that the referenced link parameter is used twice, the first time within the tr. So adding eq(2) and then  td:eq(3) for the third column does the trick.

```js
<script>
$(function() {
$('tr:has([href$="oID=238&action=edit"]):eq(2) td:eq(3)').before('<td class="dataTableContent" align="center">&nbsp;</td>');
});
$('tr:has([href$="oID=238&action=edit"]):eq(2) td:eq(3)').before('<td class="dataTableContent" align="center">&nbsp;</td>');
});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%"><table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
          <tr class="dataTableHeadingRow">
            <td class="dataTableHeadingContent">Customers</td>
            <td class="dataTableHeadingContent" align="right">Order Total</td>
            <td class="dataTableHeadingContent" align="center">Date Purchased</td>
            <td class="dataTableHeadingContent" align="right">Status</td>
            <td class="dataTableHeadingContent" align="right">Action&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="defaultSelected" class="dataTableRowSelected" onclick="document.location.href='http://localhost/...?page=1&oID=5&action=edit'">
            <td class="dataTableContent"><a href="http://localhost/...?page=1&oID=5&action=edit"><img src="images/icons/preview.gif" border="0" alt="Preview" title="Preview" /></a>&nbsp;Rainer Schmied</td>
            <td class="dataTableContent" align="right">25.53€</td>
            <td class="dataTableContent" align="center">11/28/2019 11:12:13</td>
            <td class="dataTableContent" align="right">Pending</td>
            <td class="dataTableContent" align="right"><img src="images/icon_arrow_right.gif" border="0" alt="" />&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```